# Converting Date Format In Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a Date Format (2013-12-16T11:30:00+05:30), I want to add that GMT+5.30 and display the time with the date. How do I go about this??

> for example for the above date : 12/16/2013 17:00:00, This is what i should display.

Comment: pls add some description about your jqgrid

Comment: It is 4.5.4, I have parsed raw data from the server and putting it into the column, I get the above mentioned value for the date and i have to add the 5.30 to that value and display in that column.

Comment: Could you just convert the DateTime to a value that incorporates the time offset?

Comment: @Mark: I tried Doing that with no luck :-(